# Magento - Which "Shopping Basket Price Rules" have been applied to the cart?

Tags: magento, rule

I'd like to pull out a list of "Shopping Basket Price Rules" that have been applied to the current basket. I can't find the code for this! Can you help?

I can pull out the name of the discount voucher used like this:

```
echo Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($this->getQuote()->getCouponCode(), 'code')->getRuleId())->getName();
```

But any automatically applied basket discounts have me stuck. I don't know how to look them up. I've tried var_dump on things like data from `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals()`, but Magento must be running out of memory because I just get a white screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kind of fixed this, at least enough for my purposes. I can pull out a single line from the "totals" block in the basket using the following code:

```
echo $this->renderTotal($totals['discount']);
```

This line can either be displayed on its own, or data can be extracted from it.